# Measure-Object not outputting the correct result

Tags: powershell

I am unable to understand why would it result in `0`?

```
[String] $outputVariable = "INFO: Configuring the component HPOvPerlA";
write-host $outputVariable | Select-String -pattern "INFO:" -SimpleMatch | Measure-Object -Line;
```

```
                        Lines Words                         Characters                    Property
                        ----- -----                         ----------                    --------
                            0
```

Where as if i run below then I get correct result.

```
"INFO: Configuring the component HPOvPerlA" | Select-String -pattern "INFO:" | Measure-Object -Line;
```

```
                        Lines Words                         Characters                    Property
                        ----- -----                         ----------                    --------
                            1
```

The only difference I see is `write-host` along with $variable but in my opinion this should not make any difference.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is exactly what you've identified, but seemingly dismissed, and that is `Write-Host`.

`Write-Host` sends the `$outputVariable`/string content to the console, however your intent is to send it through the pipeline. To do that you should be using `Write-Output` instead.

Examples:

```
[String] $outputVariable = "INFO: Configuring the component HPOvPerlA";
Write-Output $outputVariable | Select-String -Pattern "INFO:" -SimpleMatch | Measure-Object -Line;
```

```
Write-Output "INFO: Configuring the component HPOvPerlA" | Select-String -Pattern "INFO:" | Measure-Object -Line | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Lines;
```